# How to draw picture on a QPainter by reading the data from a byte array in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a byte (unsigned char) array. How to draw it using QPainter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QImage` instead, and pass your byte (unsigned char) array to the constructor of `QImage`.
See http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-4

Comment: I am using 8 bit Greyscale. So what wud be the format of it? Then what I have to pass in QImage::setColorCount(). Please help

Comment: I have filled all bytes of the buffer with 100. But the color is not changing. It shows always white

Comment: RGB32 expects 32bit values. I don't see a 8bit format supported expect the index-based Indexed8 (using a colormap). So you probably have to iterate and call setPixel for each pixel manually, or convert the array as neciu suggests.

Answer (score 0):

QImage docs says:

> [...]data must be 32-bit aligned, and each scanline of data in the
>   image must also be 32-bit aligned. [...]

so maybe you'll prepare your data for that?

Just make new array four time bigger than original one and fill R, B, G with your value and A with 255. Then pass this new array to QImage constructor and that's all.